# Where is svn on Mac OS X 10.8?

Tags: macos, svn

According to the [Apache Subversion home-page](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#osx), svn is bundled with Mac OS X. This is corroborated by [Apple's own Open-Source-in-Mac-OS-X directory page](http://www.apple.com/opensource/). Trying to run it on my Mountain Lion 10.8.4, however, looks like this:

```
foo:bar user$ svn
-bash: svn: command not found
```

Where has it gone to?

Answer (score 9):

[This blog](http://www.threeeyedbird.com/blog/2012/08/06/where-did-svn-go-after-upgrading-to-os-x-mountain-lion-10.8/) describes in detail how svn is now bundled with Xcode, rather than Mac OS X itself, and contains suggestions how to amend the system path to work around this issue, provided you already have Xcode installed. In short, the 'bundled' svn may now be found here:

```
foo:bar user$ which svn
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/svn
```

Comment: Yeah, beautiful place for basic Unix binaries. I symbolically linked all the binaries there to `/usr/local/bin` When I installed SVN 1.7.7 (the standard Subversion is 1.6.18), I symbolically linked everything from `/opt/subversion/bin` to `/usr/local/bin` and replaced whatever SVN links were there. I put `/usr/local/bin` as the first directory in my `$PATH`. This way, it makes it easy to manage what versions of what binaries I actually execute.

Answer (score 4):

Steps:

1. Open terminal
2. Type: `sudo nano /etc/paths`
3. Go to the end of file and paste: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin`
4. Keyboard Hit: <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>
5. Keyboard Hit: <kbd>Y</kbd>
6. After hitting <kbd>Y</kbd>, hit <kbd>enter</kbd>, otherwise the changes will not be saved. (To confirm if the changes were saved correctly, repeat steps 1 and 2.)
7. Restart the terminal and then you are ready.

For in depth details, refer:
http://www.threeeyedbird.com/blog/2012/08/06/where-did-svn-go-after-upgrading-to-os-x-mountain-lion-10.8/